Flutter application has no icon on app store connect TestFlight
I've distributed an application on testFlight. I have a 1024*1024 icon in my bundle and after I installed the application, the app has the icon but it's just not showing the icon in the app store connect websites.
Here are images for reference:


What should I do next? should I edit something on the app store connect website or edit some configurations in the Xcode before I build the bundle?

Have you had your first version approved by Apple and released yet?

not yet, just upload to testFlight

The icon will appear in AppStore Connect after your app is approved and released

The icon only appears in App Store Connect after your first build is approved and released to the store.

ok, got it. will check it after I upload to app store

You need to provide icons for all different sizes. You can generate the following icons from this website:

https://www.appicon.co/

Download the generated folder and extract the icons.
Then just copy and paste those iOS icons to the following folder:

projectDirectory/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset

or you can also import it through XCode.
It should look like the following image.

Then just clean your project and run again.

already done this at the first place
